# What is the difference between use of http and FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference() in flutter

Tags: http, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, mobile-development

We can upload and download data from firebase using both the packages. Is there some benefits of using FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().  to do the same in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Firebase plugins way better and easy to use, have a lot of Built features especially listener feature. finally almost all articles and YouTube videos work with Firebase plugins so you have a reference to learn from.